# PayPal payment variables for post to return url

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm currently using PayPal to do payments with the API as below:

```
<form id="payment" method="post" action= "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@yahoo.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/callback" />
    <input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
</form>
```

As described from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B, `rm` is set to 2 to use `POST` method for the return url after the payment process.

However, the return `POST` variables are not described in detail, and I got some variables from chrome like:

```
mc_gross:1.00
mc_currency:USD
```

which are easy to understand. But the variables like:

```
verify_sign:AIcINKz4gusKUvaiOqo3JiAvlEBFA-7ApBee-2bb5OtUUM5RhVUumd84
auth:AEH3nN1f7cUPFUFS4wPBRv6gOw6CV0BppygOu6y-vRHspA3a-ae-y2BnH1tQds1bwOG4EFqxZrcgNxLXKZdsDWg
```

which I don't find out the meaning. Possibly this should be like an encryption or checksum? If yes, how can I check the validation of these return variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how paypal payments are made.

```
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];

payment.amount = [self.paymentAmount decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:roundUp];

payment.currencyCode = @"USD";

self.PayPalReceiverEmail = [[self.photo objectForKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey] objectForKey:kPayPalReceiverEmailKey];

payment.shortDescription = self.PayPalReceiverEmail;

if (([[NSDecimalNumber notANumber] isEqualToNumber:payment.amount] ) ) {
// This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
// example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
// empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
// to handle that here.
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enter a valid amount" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
  [alert show];

}
else {
if  (!payment.processable)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Payment cannot be processed. Please contact technical support." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{
// Any customer identifier that you have will work here. Do NOT use a device- or
// hardware-based identifier.
//self.customerId = @"user-12345";
  self.customerId = [PFUser currentUser].objectId;

// Set the environment:
// - For live charges, use PayPalEnvironmentProduction (default).
// - To use the PayPal sandbox, use PayPalEnvironmentSandbox.
// - For testing, use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork.
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:self.environment];


  if (self.PayPalReceiverEmail && self.PayPalReceiverEmail.length >0 )
  {
      PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;

      if (self.PayPalClientId && self.PayPalClientId.length > 0)
      {


   paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:self.PayPalClientId
                                                                                               receiverEmail:self.PayPalReceiverEmail
                                                                                                     payerId:self.customerId
                                                                                                     payment:payment
                                                                                                    delegate:self];

          paymentViewController.hideCreditCardButton = !self.acceptCreditCards;

            }
    else
    {

       paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:kPayPalClientId
                                                                                                     receiverEmail:self.PayPalReceiverEmail
                                                                                                           payerId:self.customerId
                                                                                                           payment:payment
                                                                                                          delegate:self];

        paymentViewController.hideCreditCardButton = YES;

    }

// Setting the languageOrLocale property is optional.
//
// If you do not set languageOrLocale, then the PayPalPaymentViewController will present
// its user interface according to the device's current language setting.
//
// Setting languageOrLocale to a particular language (e.g., @"es" for Spanish) or
// locale (e.g., @"es_MX" for Mexican Spanish) forces the PayPalPaymentViewController
// to use that language/locale.

// For full details, including a list of available languages and locales, see PayPalPaymentViewController.h.
paymentViewController.languageOrLocale = @"en";


[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: But how about the return post variables?

Comment: Thanks Han for the comment. The post variables contain values sent by the sample IPN message and other information about the transaction.

To check the validation of these return variables before you can trust the contents of the message, you must first verify that the message came from PayPal. To verify the message, you must send back the contents in the exact order they were received and precede it with the command _notify-validate as in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Comment: Thank you for your patient reply. Actually I didn't use IPN, but only the return url to receive payment result details, checking if this payment is successful. You mean I have to send back the variables?

Comment: Anytime, Han.  Yes, you have to send back the variables if you want to check the validation of these return variables.  If the validation is not critically important, then you can just ignore the values in the variables and just do nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally got my website working. And it seems that the only way to send back the params is to use GET request and encode all stuff into the URL. Although it's not clever, it works anyway. :)

Comment: anytime @Han That's what we're here for.  Let me know how else I can help.  Formgram automates workflow, spreadsheets, and FileMaker Pro.